Re-Construccion de Widget al usar un TextField en un Stack - Flutter
Cuando abro o oculto el focus de el TextField del Widget _CommentTextField (se abre o cierra el teclado), el widget se PostScren es redibujado varias veces hasta que el teclado termina de aparecer o de esconderse. Esto conlleva una gran deficiencia en esta pantalla, ya que esta re-construccion reduce el rendimiento del widget en cuestion.
Me eh percatado que esto ocurre cuando utilizo el widget de Stack, ya que eh probado con un Column y esto no sucede. Alguna idea? Llevo 4 dias tratando de resolverlo. 
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:post_tree/app/infrastructure/home/community/models/post.dart';
import 'package:post_tree/app/shared/widgets/widgets.dart';
import 'package:post_tree/app/ui/home/community/post/widgets/widgets.dart';

class PostScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Post post;

  const PostScreen({super.key, required this.post});

  void sortComments() => post.sortCommentsByDate();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
        SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              child: Column(
                children: [MinimalistPost(post: post), _showCommentsList()],
              ),
            )),
        _CommentTextField(
          onSubmitComment: (value) => post.addComment(Comment(
              comment: value,
              commentDate: DateTime.now(),
              userRef: "Daniel Zamudio")),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }

  Widget _showCommentsList() {
    final comments = post.comments;
    if (comments != null) {
      return Expanded(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 70),
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: comments.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              final commentItem = post.comments![index];
              return CommentItem(commentItem: commentItem);
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    return const Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
      child: Text('Esta publicación aun no tiene comentarios'),
    );
  }
}

class _CommentTextField extends StatelessWidget {

  final Function(String value) onSubmitComment;

  _CommentTextField({required this.onSubmitComment});
  
  final TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController(text: "");
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();

  void _onSubmit() {
    onSubmitComment(_textEditingController.text);
    _textEditingController.clear();
    _focusNode.requestFocus();
  }

  bool _availableToSend() => _textEditingController.text.length > 10;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("TextField");
    return Positioned(
      bottom: 0,
      child: SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
          child: FancyBoxShadow(
            fillColor: Colors.white,
            child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                child: ValueListenableBuilder(
                  valueListenable: _textEditingController,
                  builder: (context, value, child) => TextField(
                    onTapOutside: (event) {
                      _focusNode.unfocus();
                    },
                    focusNode: _focusNode,
                    controller: _textEditingController,
                    maxLength: 255,
                    onChanged: (value) => _textEditingController.text = value,
                    onEditingComplete:
                        value.text.length < 10 ? null : _onSubmit,
                    textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      filled: true,
                      hintText: "Comentar",
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                          onPressed: value.text.length < 10 ? null : _onSubmit,
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.send)),
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                )),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


